# Extract first N characters from each string in a vector

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of strings:

```
v.string <- c('abc', 'beb', 'lol', 'heh', 'hah')
```

Is there a way of extracting the first N elements from the vector? So in the above if I want to extract the first 2, i will get:

```
'ab','be','lo','he','ha'
```

Or do I have to do a loop and use `substr` function? My vector is rather long.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are looking for `?substr`

```
 substr( v.string , start = 1 , stop = 2 )
```

(incorporating @Arun's comment) if you want to start at the second-to-last letters, you might also use the `nchar` function, so

```
# print the number of characters in each string in your character vector..
nchar( v.string ) 

# ..which gets used to..

# print the second-to-last character until the end of the string
substr( v.string , start = nchar( v.string ) - 1 , stop = nchar( v.string ) )
```

Comment: if you'd want the first `n-1` letters (assuming you string is not always having same lengths), then replace `stop = 2` with `stop = nchar(v.string) - 1`